# How to pass variable to aws s3 cp command

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to copy data from s3 bucket to my ec2 machine using `aws s3 cp` command from inside of user data script.

```
cloudwatch_path=`aws ssm get-parameter --name=/${env_lower}/cloudwatch --query=Parameter.Value`

echo $cloudwatch_path    # s3://<bucket_name>/dv-config.json

aws s3 cp "$cloudwatch_path" /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json
```

I have stored the bucket name in ssm store as there the multiple bucket names based on different environments and configuarations. So I am able to fetch the bucket name and path from the ssm store but when I am trying to use that path using a variable then I am getting an error -

```
usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>

Error: Invalid argument type
```

Any idea how to pass the variable to `aws s3 cp` command

Comment: What `env_lower` is?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws --query` returns the value with double quotes:

```
echo $cloudwatch_path    # "s3://<bucket_name>/dv-config.json"
```

I typically use `jq -r` instead to strip the quotes.

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name=/${env_lower}/cloudwatch | jq -r .Parameter.Value
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I removed the double quotes and it worked